# PHP FedEx API oAuth2 Error 422 INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION

Tags: php, json, oauth-2.0, fedex

FedEx is going to migrate to oAuth2 API for their Web Services in 2024 and I'm trying to change our shipping library to work with it. I was able to Authenticate - which is great and getting bearer token. Now I'm trying to get Rates and Transit Times. I'm using PHP. This is my script for  the API call:

```
    $token = $this->get_token();

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
        'X-locale: en_US'
    ];

    $url = "https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes";

    $payload = [];

    $payload["accountNumber"] = [
         "value" => "XXXXXXXXX"
    ];

    $payload["requestedShipment"] = [];
    $payload["requestedShipment"]["shipper"]["address"] = [
        "postalCode"    => "L4Z1X3",
        "countryCode"   => "CA"
    ];

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["recipient"]["address"] = [
        "postalCode"    => "V1Y5E1",
        "countryCode"   => "CA"
    ];

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["pickupType"] = "CONTACT_FEDEX_TO_SCHEDULE";

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["requestedPackageLineItems"][0] = [
        "weight" => [
            "units" => "KG",
            "value" => "10"
        ]
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // Added this on local system to avoid SSL error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Added this on local system to avoid SSL error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // Added this to decode the response

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $output         =   curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status    =   curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $content_type   =   curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $curlerr        =   curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // TO DEBUG OUTPUT
    echo "OUTPUT: ".$output."<br><br>";
    echo "HTTP STATUS: ".$http_status."<br><br>";
    echo "CONTENT TYPE: ".$content_type."<br><br>";
    echo "ERROR: ".$curlerr."<br><br>";
```

The response that I'm getting:

```
OUTPUT: {"transactionId":"874d6e61-d390-4410-a949-76d11e2ae67a","errors":[{"code":"INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION","message":"Invalid field value in the input"}]}

HTTP STATUS: 422

CONTENT TYPE: application/json

ERROR:
```

I have a feeling that my JSON formatting may not be correct or missing something. I tried `addslashes(json_encode($payload))` - it returns the same thing. I checked curl documentation for maybe any option that I'm missing - can't see what I can add to make it work.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What documentation are you basing this on? The spinner on https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-bw/catalog/rate/v1/docs.html never finishes loading for me, but the payload example there starts with `"accountNumber": { "value": "Your account number" },`, which looks like it would already be the first thing you got wrong in your data structure ...?

Comment: @CBroe you are correct. When I was posting the question I used code sample where I tried changing accountNumber structure testing if that was the issue. The API structure still returns that error. I updated the question with the proper structure.

Answer (score 0):

So, after trial and error I figured out the solution for my problem. If anybody faces the same issue this is what worked for me:

1. Adding headers 'Pragma: no-cache' and 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store' to curl request.
2. Adding rateRequestType to the JSON schema for the request.

Below is the working code. My development environment is on Windows 11 (WAMP).

```
    $token = $this->get_token();

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
        'X-locale: en_US',
        'Pragma: no-cache',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store'
    ];

    $url = "https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes";

    $payload["accountNumber"] = [
        "value" => "XXXXXXXX"
    ];

    $payload["rateRequestControlParameters"]["returnTransitTimes"] = true;

    $payload["requestedShipment"] = [];

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["shipper"]["address"] = [
        "postalCode"    => "L4Z1X3",
        "countryCode"   => "CA"
    ];

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["recipient"]["address"] = [
        "postalCode"    => "V2A5E1",
        "countryCode"   => "CA"
    ];

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["pickupType"] = "CONTACT_FEDEX_TO_SCHEDULE";

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["requestedPackageLineItems"][0] = [
        "weight" => [
            "units" => "KG",
            "value" => 10
        ]
    ];

    $payload["requestedShipment"]["rateRequestType"] = ["ACCOUNT"];
    $payload["requestedShipment"]["shipDateStamp"] = "2023-08-18";      

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // Added this on local system to avoid SSL error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Added this on local system to avoid SSL error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // Added this to decode the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $output         =   curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status    =   curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $content_type   =   curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $curlerr        =   curl_error($ch);
    $header_out     =   curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // TO DEBUG OUTPUT
    echo "OUTPUT: ".$output."<br><br>";
    echo "HTTP STATUS: ".$http_status."<br><br>";
    echo "CONTENT TYPE: ".$content_type."<br><br>";
    echo "ERROR: ".$curlerr."<br><br>";
```